# Constant Gauss curvature from bipolar projections.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Please help finding z-coordinate for constant positive and negative Gauss curvatures in Mongé form :

$$ x= \sqrt{R^2 + T^2} + R \cos u ,\, y= R \sin u ,\, z= f(x,y). $$

$  R,T $ are constants.

(Earlier seen Cassinian Ovals projection used to build up such forms, this may have been already done before?)